# How to output the output data of `exec.Command` without broken characters

Tags: windows, go, cmd, encoding, decoding

I tried running this source code to get the output of cmd.

```
cmd, err := exec.Command("systeminfo").Output()
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
fmt.Println(string(cmd))
return cmd, nil
```

But the result is like this picture.

[image]

The output includes Korean, and only English and numbers are displayed, all other characters are broken.

I'm not sure how to solve these encoding problems.

Comment: golang.org/x/text/encoding and the packages below.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with this code

```
//import
//"golang.org/x/text/encoding/korean"
//"golang.org/x/text/transform"
cmd, err := exec.Command("systeminfo").Output()
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

bufs := new(bytes.Buffer) 
wr := transform.NewWriter(bufs, korean.EUCKR.NewDecoder())
wr.Write(cmd)
wr.Close()
```